# Flash movie doesn't go fullscreen unless a button is clicked

Tags: actionscript-3, fullscreen

I have a Flash movie to be displayed in fullscreen on a kiosk. Also, It needs to run in a browser window because I'm using JavaScript to reload the page for resetting the movie.

The problem is, it doesn't go fullscreen when I put the following line to the constructor:

```
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
```

But it works fine if I put the line to a button's click handler.

Note: It doesn't work if just call the handler function with a null parameter.

How can I make it fullscreen as soon as it opens?

Comment: if you're creating a kiosk application you might want to consider building a standalone application in AIR, which doesn't require user input to activate full screen mode as well as having a much richer set of APIs for system accessibility and (usually) overall better performance.

Comment: why do u need the page updated with js?

Comment: User interaction is needed to go full screen period, anything else would be a security violation. In other words a mouse click has to be in the stack trace for that line of code to work.

Comment: The problem lies in the whole refresh thing imo. I mean. you are refreshing the page so that the movie restarts. Why dont u just reset the movie with actionscript? And the first time u launch it you just make a click. That way you can also make a standalone swf file as mentioned in the answers. Ps. I have no idea what a Kiosk is

Comment: All your questions are understandable. But the thing is, the movie is made by somebody else and has a very ugly code to read. So I don't want to break things while trying to reset. It's not a timeline movie unfortunately. So I thought it would be easy if I place it on a web page and refresh. But now I made another movie to load and unload to have the reset effect done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to security restrictions user input is required to goto full screen when playing inside a HTML player.

Quote Adobe docs:

> Full-screen mode is initiated in response to a mouse click or key
>   press by the user; the movie cannot change Stage.displayState without
>   user input. Flash runtimes restrict keyboard input in full-screen
>   mode. Acceptable keys include keyboard shortcuts that terminate
>   full-screen mode and non-printing keys such as arrows, space, Shift,
>   and Tab keys. Keyboard shortcuts that terminate full-screen mode are:
>   Escape (Windows, Linux, and Mac), Control+W (Windows), Command+W
>   (Mac), and Alt+F4.

If you are running in a kiosk consider using the stand alone SWF player which doesn' have these restrictions

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: you can't.

As mentioned in [the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#displayState), you can only change the displayState as a reaction to user interaction, be that a mouse click or key press.  This is a usability feature that I wouldn't expect to change any time soon.

Note that this restriction only applies to SWF content running in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is "you can't".  For security reasons, operations like this can only be done on a user event.  Otherwise, you could take over the user's desktop and do all kinds of nefarious things like presenting a bogus login dialog.

Comment: Thanks but, virtually, I am the user here.